# Log4j2 conversion pattern for logger names

Tags: java, log4j2, string-matching

I'm trying to trim logger names in Log4j2 Core's **PatternLayout**.

Examples logger name:

```
com.test1.test2.test3.test4.test5.ClassName
```

Expected output:

```
c.t.t.t.t.test5.ClassName
```

In the docs I can only trim from the end not from beginning.

Any suggestions would be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no pattern that allows you to abbreviate all components except the last two. This has been reported in [LOG4J2-2785](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LOG4J2-2785) and there is work in progress on this issue.

Answer (score 1):

Examples:

```
    <Console name="ConsoleAppender" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
        <PatternLayout pattern="%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} [%p] %c{1.} %msg%xEx%n"/>
    </Console>
```

%c{1.}  means output the first character of package name.

Comment: the above pattern gives me like this
```c.t.t.t.t.t.ClasName
```
But I want display the last package ```c.t.t.t.t.test5.ClasName```

Comment: You can change the pattern :   “%c{1.}” .